# function that accepts either url or string?

Tags: php, protocols, file-get-contents

I have a function that I want to be able to accept either an html string, or a resource that `file_get_contents()` can work on.

My basic idea is

```
function something($source){
  $local = true;
  foreach(array('http://', 'https://') as $protocol)
    if(stripos($source, $protocol) === 0)
      $local = false;
  //more stuff
}
```

which works,
But I am curious, is there a better way of doing this, and if not, what other protocols can `file_get_contents()` handle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal way.
[Supported Protocols and Wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php)